# Copying an entire table with Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, copy

I'm trying to copy the contents of one table into another in Postgres, however it appears some rows aren't being copied correctly:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   PGError: ERROR: column "email_date" is
>   of type timestamp without time zone
>   but expression is of type character
>   varying HINT: You will need to rewrite
>   or cast the expression.

Is there any way I can have it automatically skip (or ignore) invalid rows?

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0; INSERT INTO emails3 SELECT * FROM emails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, it's not a problem of "some invalid rows", you have incompatible types 
for the `email_date` column. Either fix that, or write the explicit conversion in the query.

UPDATE: If (as it seems) you want to copy the contents *and* the schema of the table (i.e. create a new table with the same schema and copy the contents), you can do it simply with a [**SELECT INTO**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-selectinto.html).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's emails3 that has the wrong column type, or emails? Is there an easy way for me to check?

I'm using Rails, and when I type "Email" into the console to view the model for the emails table, it shows that the email_date column is of type datetime. For Rails migrations and Postgres, this corresponds with "timestamp".

Comment: See the schema of the tables -dont you have access to a psql console? I guess the source is a character and the target (emails3.email_date) is a timestamp. But this does not say which one is "wrong".

Comment: Okay great. In order to ensure the two tables had a perfectly similar structure, I ended up doing this: "CREATE TABLE emails3 AS SELECT * FROM emails WHERE 1=2". After that my INSERT INTO was able to go through. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ha, that was ok, but a little dirty :-) I updated the answer with a much simpler alternative to accomplish that.